# check table from my sql query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I'm checking duplicated data from tables. I have a problem that from where data selected. My code is:

```
$sub_cat = array(); 
$select = array("core_network","daisy_chain", "rf_bts", "rf_power", "rf_transmission");
$d='0';
for ($i=0;$i<=4;$i++){
    $SQL = "SELECT sub_cat FROM (".$select[$i].") WHERE location=('".$id."')";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    $cs=$d;

    if ($result) {
        while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if(!in_array($db_field['sub_cat'],$sub_cat)) {
                $sub_cat[]= $db_field['sub_cat'];
                $cs++;
                $d=$cs;
                $d--;
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to know that `sub_cat` selected from which `$select[i]`. How to find it?

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values, do this:

```
$sub_cat = array(); 
$select = array("core_network","daisy_chain", "rf_bts", "rf_power", "rf_transmission");
$d='0';
for ($i=0;$i<=4;$i++){
    $SQL = "SELECT sub_cat FROM (" . $select[$i] . ") WHERE location=('".$id."')";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL); // deprecated - use PDO

    $cs = $d;

    if ($result) {
        while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if(!in_array($db_field['sub_cat'], $sub_cat)) {
                $table = $select[$i];
                $sub_cat[$table][] = $db_field['sub_cat'];

                // I have no clue what's going on here in your example:
                $cs++;
                $d=$cs;
                $d--;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Then, to retrieve it:

```
foreach ($sub_cat as $table_name => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $row) {
        // output values here
    }
}
```

Comment: hello i have no experience for using foreach can you explain more for me please

Comment: `foreach` loops through each value in an array, and assigns the value to a `$key => $value` variables. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php. Remember to mark as answer if this answered your original question.